# Move camera with button in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want move Main Camera with button. Its my game play :

[image]

its my scene:

[image]

want when click in button, main camera move to right in another pic. 
This is my script for button:

```
public void Uss(GameObject camera) {

    Vector3 temp = transform.position; 
    temp.x += 0.1f; 
    camera.transform.position = temp; 

}
```

Comment: The `transform` is the transform of the button, not the camera. You should move the `GameObject` of the main camera instead.

Comment: edit my code .but still not working

Comment: The answer is edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, the button is moved, not the camera. You should move the GameObject of the main camera instead.

```
Transform cameraTransform; 
void Start()
{
    cameraTransform = Camera.main.gameObject.transform;
}
public void Update()
{
    cameraTransform.Translate(7, 0, 0);
}
```

But I recommend you write the logic in the `onClick` handler of the button like below.

Attach a script to the button `GameObject`

```
float step = 100;//find a proper value for this
void Start()
{
    Button b = gameObject.GetComponent<Button>();
    b.onClick.AddListener(
        ()=>
        {
            Camera.main.gameObject.transform.Translate(step, 0, 0);
        }
    );
}
```

The step value is dependent on the size of your pictures.

I haven't tested the script but it should work in that way.

Comment: if i want when i click button camera move from pick1 to pick 2 nice and slowly ? ho can i ? like this :Vector3 pos = transform.position;
  pos.x += 1;
  pos.x = Mathf.Clamp(pos.x, 0F, 300F);
  transform.position = pos;  but im new and cant combin this codes

Comment: nice and slowly? Refer to [this post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/29751/gradually-moving-an-object-up-to-speed-rather-then.html).